# Is xelatex compatible with pgf masks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex

When making my presentation with beamer I use xelatex to get nice fonts or I use pgf package to make images with transparent backgrounds. Unfortunately, I cannot use both at once as xelatex ignores \pgfdeclaremask. Is this a bug of xelatex? If yes, is there a work around?

Compiling this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
  Some text here.
  \pgfdeclaremask{bmask}{pic-mask.jpg}
  \pgfimage[mask=bmask,interpolate=true,width=4cm]{pic.jpg}
\end{document}
```

with pdflatex works just fine. But if I compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arctic Regular}
\begin{document}
  Some text here.
  \pgfdeclaremask{bmask}{pic-mask.jpg}
  \pgfimage[mask=bmask,interpolate=true,width=4cm]{pic.jpg}
\end{document}
```

with xelatex, the mask is just ignored.

lualatex seams to do the job. But if someone could comment about xelatex it would be great too.

Comment: I don’t know about pgf masks and `xelatex`, but have you tried using your preferred fonts with `lualatex`?

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Comment: Did you put it inside a node or pgfnode?

Comment: if you use latex/dvips pgf gives a warning: `Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support image masks. This warning is given only once on input line 6.` xetex+xdvipdfmx is a similar workflow so it looks like the warning code is missing from the xetex def file but that basically masks are not going to work. (tested in texlive 2016)